# How to send multiple of the same key/parameter via POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

If I had to send a bunch of post parameters along an HTTP request, all with the same name, how do I construct the `data` object to post?

Picture a form with some check boxes, they all have the same `name` attribute but with different values (if they're checked):

```
<input name="color" value="red"/>
<input name="color" value="green"/>
<input name="color" value="blue"/>
```

I want to construct this in ruby (but it needs to be created dynamically depending on what was selected on the form):

```
data = {
    "color" => "red",
    "color" => "green",
    "color" => "blue"
}
```

And then send the data to some URL:

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(url, data)
```

I cannot control the receiving end, so I have to send the parameters as it expects to receive them. How?

Answer (score 7):

```
data = {
    "color" => "red",
    "color" => "green",
    "color" => "blue"
}
```

You can't have that, as it would result in Ruby having a single key:

```
> { a: 1, a: 2, a: 3 }
=> {:a=>3}
```

But you can have this:

```
data = {
  colors: [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ]
}
```

To achieve that, use this HTML notation:

```
<input name="color[]" value="red"/>
<input name="color[]" value="green"/>
<input name="color[]" value="blue"/>
```

This will translate to a GET request as:

```
?color[]=red&color[]=green&color[]=blue
```

And to POST as:

```
color[]: red
color[]: green
color[]: blue
```

Both will provide, on the server side:

```
params[ :color ] == [ 'red', 'green', 'blue' ]
```

If you *have* to provide params that way, you can take advantage of the array notation of `Net::HTTP.post_form`. In your HTML:

```
<input name="color[]" value="red"/>
<input name="color[]" value="green"/>
<input name="color[]" value="blue"/>
```

Then, in your controller:

```
colors = params.delete( :color )
Net::HTTP.post_form( uri, { 'color' => colors }.merge( params ) )
```

`Net::HTTP.post_form` accept params having an array as value, but do not touch the key notation. So, if you would change the `"color"` key to the usual parameter convention, you would use `"color[]"`.

That's exactly what you do *not* want to do in your case. Leaving the key as `"color"` will achieve the desired result.

Comment: Right, but this is being posted to another form (not on my site). So I need to pass multiple "color" parameters but with different values. I'll probably have to build the parameter string to send along instead of trying to send an object.

Answer (score 6):

Can you not simply:

```
<input name="color[]" value="red"/>
<input name="color[]" value="green"/>
<input name="color[]" value="blue"/>
```

For other ideas, you can also see this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614762/multiple-key-value-pairs-in-http-post-where-key-is-the-same-name?rq=1).

Comment: The receiving end is not rails-hosted.

Comment: ok, then it looks like you'll need to use the method in the link above. you may want to update the question to specify that you cannot control the receiving side