# How to accept multiple URL parameters in Rails with the same key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url-parameters

In Rails, when you want to send a list of values through a single array parameter, [you usually do so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2614762/334761) by suffixing the URL parameter key with `[]`. For example, the query string `?foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3` is parsed as

```
params = { "foo" => [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

But for `?foo=1&foo=2&foo=3`, only the last argument shows up in the params hash:

```
params = { "foo" => 3 }
```

Everything's fine while you can control the URL format; you can just use the `[]` syntax. But what if the URL is constructed by a remote system that you cannot influence, and that insists on the second format? How can one get the arguments unpacked properly?

Comment: You are going to need to parse the URI manually, you can use [URI::decode_www_form](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form)

Comment: go through the https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable - replacement for Ruby's URI module.

Answer (score 2):

Using the hint from @maxcal I came up with this solution (to avoid adding yet more gems to this completely bloated app that I'm working on):

```
current_query_string = URI(request.url).query
foo_values = URI::decode_www_form(current_query_string).
  select { |pair| pair[0] == "foo" }.
  collect { |pair| pair[1] }
```